# VSTS File Copy Issue

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am using Microsoft VSTS and as part of a release I am uploading artefacts to an Azure Storage account.  I am uploading 3 files:

1. RELEASES
2. setup.exe
3. setup.nupkg

Strangely enough, it copies the first two files but seems to have an issue with the last one.  I get this less-than-helpful error message:

> Upload to container: 'releases' in storage account: 'mystorage' with
>   blob prefix: '' failed with error: '' For more info please refer to
>   https://aka.ms/azurefilecopyreadme

Comment: Please refer this issue (https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/1257) to make sure the Azure File Copy task on your agent machine is updated. And can you also add a release variable `system.debug` as `true`, and show detail logs here?

Comment: Solved it Marina, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the source of this problem. Basically, I had cancelled an upload to the blob container from Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer earlier in the day.  When trying to upload a file of the same name as the one that I had cancelled, this error was being thrown.  I re-created the container and it's all fine now.